# How to set coach marks for action buttons?

Tags: android, action-button

I wanna make coach marks for action buttons but I don't now how to get their positions and paddings on action bar.
You can see what I have in mind but I cant reach in this picture:

[image]

I have a translucent overlay layout but I wanna show icons I'm describing in full transparency.

Is there any way to do that?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
in fact these are the values I need to find since they are different in different devices

[image]

EDIT2:
using Nigam Patro's solution, I ended up this:

[image]

code:

```
...
int[] filterPosition = new int[2];
findViewById(R.id.action_filter).getLocationOnScreen(filterPosition);
View filterDummy = coachMark.findViewById(R.id.filter_dummy);
filterDummy.setX(filterPosition[0]);
filterDummy.setY(filterPosition[1]);
...
```

layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/translucent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/filter_dummy"
        android:layout_width="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_filter_false" />

</RelativeLayout
```

EDIT3:
code:

```
...
int[] filterPosition = new int[2];
View filterView = findViewById(R.id.action_filter);
filterView.getLocationOnScreen(filterPosition);
int paddingTop = filterView.getPaddingTop();
int paddingBottom = filterView.getPaddingBottom();
int paddingLeft = filterView.getPaddingLeft();
int paddingRight = filterView.getPaddingRight();
View filterDummy = coachMark.findViewById(R.id.filter_dummy);
int statusBarHeight = 0;
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0) {
    statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}
filterDummy.setX(filterPosition[0]);
filterDummy.setY(filterPosition[1] - statusBarHeight);
filterDummy.setPadding(paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom);
...
```

Result:
[image]

Very close,but still not right

Comment: The overlay view is a layout or image?

Comment: Its a Relative Layout.

Comment: OK, the actionbar is andorid actionbar or layout?

Comment: Find the below answer.

Comment: @nigam Thanks to U my friend I'm very close to it, but still. . .

Comment: @nigam but it still isn't acceptable, don't you have any idea?

Comment: No, bro... I only tried with difference place and this logic for some other work.'

Answer (score 1):

By the following you can get the view from the actionbar

```
findViewById(R.id.menu_item);
```

and by using this method you can get the view's X & Y position

```
View.getLocationOnScreen()
```

So, after getting the X & Y position get the height of status bar,

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() { 
      int result = 0;
      int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
      if (resourceId > 0) {
          result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
      } 
      return result;
}
```

Now differentiate the Y with the statusbar height, you will get the original height y position of item inside activity.

X values is the left margin, Y value is top margin.

Comment: getLocationOnScreen() is not defined for menu items and trying to cast menu item to view throws an exeption

Comment: well, I taught one can not access menu items using that method, but still it doesn't work properly. the icon i tried to position is below and slightly to the left of the original icon.

Comment: @MamadTell then post your code what you have tried.

Comment: Ok, I forgot to update one thing, here you need to differentiate the satusbar height from Y.

Comment: Hey, once check with the modified answer.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for your help, y is perfectly working but x still isn't right

Comment: and also padding, I set padding manually but it wont be right on other devices

Comment: may be there is some padding to the action button in action bar.

Comment: May be the action buttons, in action bar have some padding?

Comment: yes there is,but i dont know how to find it, and i cant set it using style because AB padding must be generated buy android on runtime

Comment: maybe the same way we found position! I will try it :))

Comment: Ok, and let me know the solution also.